# Android - What happens to Threads when a Activity finishes?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have an `Activity`, which starts a `Thread` to do some work. What happens if the user presses the Back button, or the UI thread calls `finish()` to the thread?

Will the activity wait for the thread to `finish()` before the activity is destroyed?

Does the thread complete its work after the activity gets destroyed?

Comment: thanks for editing and sorry for my bad english ;-)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37778073/3073945

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread will do its work, but you can't use any callbacks to your activity.

Comment: So i get a NullPointer Exception (the Thread will update UI through a Handle-Object) if the Activity is finished, because theres no reference anymore, but the Thread do its work ? (Just for understanding)

Comment: No, rather you will get Bad window token or something else. This is a good practise to set activit instance to thread object directly and remove in onDestroy method.

Answer (score 1):

Thread will run in background until thread gets kill.Thread wont get destroyed in your case.